# How to identify type of web server

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, webserver, url-routing

I am currently trying to resolve routing issues on my angularjs project. And one of the solutions that I would like to try is to create url rewrite rules as stated [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode). However, I do not know which type of server I am using. Temporarily, I am using a free web hosting service provided by [www.x10hosting.com](http://www.x10hosting.com).

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `$ curl -I -L www.x10hosting.com` reveals `Server: cloudflare-nginx`

Comment: Tried it with my website's exact URL and it returned the same. If you post this solution as an answer I would happily chose it as the correct answer :) Thanks a lot!